# Is there a why to draw a straight rule line outside of object

Tags: units

My object has different parts but overall when it is combine together it need to be specifically 64 cm, so I need to draw a specifically straight rule line to use it as a reference. Is there a way to draw a straight rule line or any better idea?

Comment: so if you create a plane and change its dimension to 0.64 in the operator box or in the Transform panel (on the right of the 3D view activated with N), is it not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid for precise measurements

- Switch to orthographic view (*View > Orthographic*)
- Use top/side view (*View > Viewpoint*)
- enable *Absolute Snap* to Increment

When zooming, the grid will go from meters > centimeters> milimeters.

[image]